# Java - More Precise Rethrown Feature

Tags: java, exception, rethrow

on oracle oficial site write:(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#rethrow)

> In detail, in Java SE 7 and later, when you declare one or more exception types in a catch clause, and rethrow the exception handled by this catch block, the compiler verifies that the type of the rethrown exception meets the following conditions:
>
> - The try block is able to throw it.
> - There are no other preceding catch blocks that can handle it.
> - #### It is a subtype or supertype of one of the catch clause's exception parameters.

Please concentrate on third point (It is a subtype or supertype of one of the catch clause's exception parameters.)

What it really means with that? Could you show me examples of that? I can't understand it clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subtype part is pretty straightforward - since all subtypes *are* also their parent type, it's trivially legal to allow any subtype to be caught and rethrown. I believe that's been the case since day one (or at least further back than I can remember off the top of my head.)

As for the supertype, that was an enhancement added in Java 7. Take the following example:

```
public class Demo {

    static class Exception1 extends Exception{}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception1 {
        try {
            throw new Exception1();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

You might initially expect this not to compile, because the `main()` method only declares that it throws a type of `Exception1`, yet the catch parameter specifies `Exception`. Clearly not all `Exception` objects are `Exception1`.

However, the `catch` parameter is a supertype of `Exception1` (fulfilling the supertype requirement of the excert above), and the type of the exception thrown is the same as the type declared in the `throws` statement on the method. The compiler can therefore verify that rethrowing this exception is valid in this context, and compilation succeeds.

Comment: The only part that I didn't understand is the subtype. If you can give any examples of a scenario which happens that I'll be very thankful cuz' I'm from Brazil and some things in English is not clearly for me. Thank you again!